DROOLS 8 - How to use RuleUnit to get fired rules
I would like to log fired rules in drools 8 in an not cloud app.
I find "beforeMatchFired" but it needs a ksession to work.
Is it possible to list fired rules using RuleUnit in drools 8 ?
thanks,
Richard.

This is kind of like saying "I have a class definition, can I use it to find all objects created from it" -- the session is what is actually being fired; the rule unit is just the rule definitions, data sources, etc. The session can tell you what rules were fired (with some configuration); the rule unit can just tell you what the rules are.

Ok, thanks for your answer it made me things clearer about the aim of the RunleUnit. But rules are fired without sessions when using RuleUnit. So is there a way to get the session from the RuleUnitInstance or the RuleUnitProvider to make me able to get fired rules ?
